# JPQL how to fetch data from one table using multiple joins?

Tags: join, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I need to fetch list of instances from one table which are related parent-child, but no constraint was set on the relation column. Three level hierarchy is possible.
I wrote following query

```
"select distinct s, s1, s2 from SomeTable s" +
            " join RelatedTable rt on s.id = rt.someId and rt.id = :paramId" +
            " left join fetch SomeTable s1 on s1.parentId = s.id" +
            " left join fetch SomeTable  s2 on s2.parentId = s1.id"
```

Let's say on top level i have one instance, on bottom - ten instances, in sql console i can see data joined as expected, but in java code i have List with 10 instances of top level. What do i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with native query and sql union.